# What db and storage are people using for SaaS OLTP and OLAP offerings

Tags: storage, database-performance, saas

I work for a privately held SaaS company and we are reviewing some of our architectural decisions around database and storage. Knowing that others have gone before us, I am wondering if I might "stand on the shoulders of giants" by hearing what other SaaS companies are using for their DB and storage platforms.

We have the obvious requirements of 99.9%+ availability, sub second page renders and elastic scaling, but as an IT Ops guy, I also want it to be lightweight to manage.

I am very interested to hear from people on both coasts to see what others in this space are doing.

Comment: Both coasts? You do realise that there are people from *all over the world* here, right? I'm also not quite sure why where we're located should have any bearing on our answers...

Comment: Mark, forgive my geographically myopic comment... of course I understand that there are people all over the World, and I welcome all to answer.

Answer (score 1):

My employer is a SaaS company and we are a Microsoft shop for the most part.  We use SQL Server on the back end, and ASP.NET on the front and middle tiers.  As we move to our new CoLo we'll be moving into a VMware hosted solution so that we can add more web and/or app servers as needed easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With SQL are you licensed through their SPLA program?

Comment: Yes we are licensed through their SPLA license so we are basically renting our SQL license.